# Python timed scheduler

Tags: scheduling, python-3.3

Okay, so I'm working on a scheduler and I was thinking of something like, timeOut(3,print,'hello') and it would print hello every three seconds, I have tried some methods but all failed. Also Using time.sleep for this wouldn't quite work because I need to run other tasks as well besides just one

Edit:
I found out how to do what I needed, sorry for being confusing but this did the trick for what I needed, thanks for answering everyone.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
         self.objectives = set()
    class Objective:
         pass
    def interval(self,timeout,function,*data):
        newObjective = self.Objective()
        newObjective.Class = self
        newObjective.timeout = time.time()+timeout
        newObjective.timer = timeout
        newObjective.function = function
        newObjective.repeate = True
        newObjective.data = data
        self.objectives.add(newObjective)
        return True
    def runObjectives(self):
         timeNow = time.time()
         for objective in self.objectives:
             timeout = objective.timer
             if objective.timeout <= timeNow:
                 objective.function(*objective.data)
                 if objective.repeate:
                     objective.timeout = timeNow + timeout
                     self.main()
                 else:
                     self.objectives.remove(objective)
                     print('removed')
    def main(self):
         while True:
             self.runObjectives()
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library includes a module called `sched` for scheduling. It can be adapted to work in a variety of environments using the `delayfunc` constructor parameter. Using it your question would likely read:

```
def event():
    scheduler.enter(3, 0, event, ()) # reschedule
    print('hello')
```

Now it depends on how you run the other tasks. Are you using an event loop? It probably has a similar scheduling mechanism (at least `twisted` has `callLater` and `GObject` has `timeout_add`). If all else fails, you can spawn a new thread and execute a `sched.scheduler` with `time.sleep` there.